# How to solve "object of type 'Course' has no len()" error that I am getting after using paginator in a view function?

Tags: django, pagination, foreign-keys, django-pagination

This is my model. I have a many to one relationship.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Coursegk(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option_two = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option_three = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option_four = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="display")
```

This is my views.py page

```
def showcourses(request):
    details = Course.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(details, 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'data':page_obj})


def displaymcqpage(request, courses_id):
    displaymcq = Course.objects.get(id=courses_id)
    paginator = Paginator(displaymcq, 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'coursegk.html', {'display':page_obj})
```

Now paginator is working fine for the index.html page. But  when I go to coursegk.html page from index.html page I am getting "object of type 'Course' has no len()" error. How to use paginator for the displaymcqpage function?

Comment: Paginating `displaymcq` makes no sense: that is a single object, so how is pagination supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use paginator for the `displaymcqpage` function?

**You don't**. This is a *detail view*: you are showing details for a *single* `Course` object. Pagination means that you have a *collection* of objects, and you show a subset of these, but here there is a single `Course` determined by the `courses_id` parameter, hence pagination makes no sense.

You can paginate the `Coursegk` objects related to that `Course` with:

```
def displaymcqpage(request, courses_id):
    displaymcq = Course.objects.get(id=courses_id)
    paginator = Paginator(displaymcq.display.all(), 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'coursegk.html', {'dta': displaymcq, 'coursegks': page_obj})
```

and here we thus paginate the related `Coursegk` objects, but then we do *not* paginate the `Course` records.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: I have a collection of questions for each course. And I want to show only two questions per page. For that I need pagination. How to do it?

Comment: @Pogbapogba: then you paginate the queryset of the related objects, as is specified in the second paragraph.